# In IIS, Can multiple Applications within same Website share some Common libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, bin

Help needed! I am new to IIS Administration and trying to host my ASP.NET Web Application.

My Web application looks similar to the one below:

[image]

I want **Parent**, **Child-One** and **Child-Two** to run as separate Applications and can be accessed as `parent.com`, `parent.com/child-one` and `parent.com/child-two` respectively.

The reason why I opted for this Project structure is to check if it is possible to Re-use some libraries present in **Bin** folder of Parent in **Child-One** and **Child-Two**.

Is it possible to re-use some DLLs from Bin folder in Parent, inside Child-One and Child-Two, Or do I have to create 3 separate projects?

Answer (score 1):

You show a single project with some folders inside. The location of **`bin`** folders is not very relevant. More important is that there is only one **`References`** node (as with every .NET project), and whatever you **add there** is available for the whole project. You do that with Right-Click + Add Reference...

You don't need the separate **`bin`** at subfolder level, but if you insist on placing DLLs there then it will also work, as long as you set `Copy Local` to `True` in the **`References`** node (meaning that on Build the referenced DLL is copied to the output folder).

Visual Studio itself will always default to working with the root **`bin`**, e.g. if you add NuGet packages, then that is where their DLLs go, and you shouldn't mess with that.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am using Membership Framework for Authentication. And I want, all those 3 projects to have their own state of Authentication. Will that be possible?

Comment: Not with this structure, because you don't have 3 projects, you have just 1, so right now it also deploys as one website or web application. For that you'll need to create 3 projects: Parent, Child1 and Child2 in the main solution. You can then add references from project Child1 pointing to the `Parent\bin` folder. Each project will then deploy its own copy of the referenced DLLs.

Comment: `Each project will then deploy its own copy of the referenced DLLs` . It means multiple copies of same DLL will exist across those 3 projects. Isn't it? Hmmm! Can u kindly let me know if there's any way to avoid redundant DLLs?

Comment: 'any way to avoid redundant DLLs' - That might be possible, but AFAIK for that your DLLs need to be signed and you need to put them in the GAC (usually `c:\Windows\assembly`) on the webserver. Usually a lot more trouble than it's worth; my advice is don't worry about a couple of duplicated DLLs, having so many GB or even TB of storage these days.

Comment: Yes, makes Sense. Thanks